# Only list unique files based on partial filename

Tags: files, grep

For example I have many files that look like the output below, I'm trying to get a list of all the unique file names but disregard the characters to the right of the "-". I have tried `ls -la | grep ....- | sort --unique` and some variations but that does not give the output I need

```
4855-00160880.psi
4855-00160980.ps
4855-00160980.psi
5355-00160880.ps
5355-00160880.psi
5355-00160980.ps
5355-00160980.psi
5855-00160880.ps
5855-00160880.psi
5855-00160980.ps
5855-00160980.psi
5855-00160A80.ps
5855-00160A80.psi
```

Ideally I would like the output to show something like

```
4855
5355
5855
```

Answer (score 6):

Since [you really don't want to parse `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), this should do the trick:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec basename "{}" \; | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort -u
```

Comment: But then this solution is not immune from some of the issues associated with parsing the output from `ls`, is it?

Comment: It could break if a filename contains a newline, yes. But that's just one of the many, many things which is wrong with `ls`, and probably acceptable in the OP's scenario.

Answer (score 5):

How's this?

```
printf "%-4.4s\n" ????-* | uniq
```

The shell expands the wildcard in alphabetical order and passes the result as arguments to `printf`. The format string truncates each argument to four characters and adds a newline. Now all that remains is to remove adjacent duplicates.

If you don't know the number of digits before the hyphen, but you have an idea, you can loop over some candidates:

```
for expr in '??' '???' '????' '?????'  # Quoted (!)
do
    printf "%-${#expr}.${#expr}\n" $expr-* |  # Unquoted!
    uniq
done
```

This uses the Bash-only [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `$[#var}` which obtains the string length of `$var`.

Notice the trickery of quoting the wildcards to avoid their expansion in the loop initialization, then using the variable unquoted inside the loop (which is a no-no in most other cases).

Comment: What if the number of digits preceding the hyphen is unknown?

Comment: Updated with a possible solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

Worth adding `-type f` to DopeGhoti's answer, to avoid that bogus `.` result.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec basename "{}" \; | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort -u
.
4855
5355
5855
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename "{}" \; | cut -d'-' -f1 | sort -u
4855
5355
5855
$
```

If wishing to keep similar to your original attempt, you could use this (bad, as it parses `ls` though!)

```
ls -1 | grep ^....-  | cut -c1-4 | sort --unique
```

awk based solution, still parsing ls

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $1}' | sort --unique
```

No real need to sort in each of these cases, since `ls` output is already sorted, so can just use `uniq`.

```
ls -1 | awk -F- '{print $1}' | uniq
```

sed based solution

```
ls -1 | sed 's/-.*//' | uniq
```

find / sed solution that avoids parsing ls

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/-.*//g' | sort --unique
```

If always 4 digits before the "-" then this is quite elegant

```
find . -type f -printf "%.4f\n" | sort -u
```

Comment: ```find . -type f -iname '*.php' -exec grep "STRING-I-NEED-TO-FIND" {} + | sed 's/:.*//g' | sort --unique``` - thanks for the nudge in the the `unique` direction!

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
myfiles=(*-*(.))
print -rl -- ${(u)myfiles[@]%%-*}
```

This saves all regular file names that contain at least one dash in an array. It then uses parameter expansion on each element of the array to remove the first dash and everything that follows. Any duplicate elements are removed via the `(u)` flag.
To select hidden files too, use `myfiles=(*-*(.D))`